# Delete all null rows - Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

basic question.

I need to delete all null/blank rows of a table in my database. Trouble is there is no way to know how many fields there are, or the names of the fields before the delete.  And I need to verify every field is null/blank before deleting. Not sure how to query for this in Access VBA.

In all the examples I find, they have a field name they can test for blanks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you tag excel when you want access?

Comment: @findwindow You are correct. Have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change TestTabke to your table name. If you have an AutoNumber field, it must be skipped. I am using DAO. If you want ADO, convert the following code.

```
Function DeleteEmptyRows()
    Dim db As DAO.database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Dim rs As DAO.recordSet
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("TestTable")
    Do Until rs.EOF
        For inx = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            If IsNull(rs.Fields(inx).Value) Or Len(Trim(rs.Fields(inx).Value)) = 0 Then
                Else: Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If rs.Fields.Count = inx Then
            rs.Delete
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

End Function
```